# How to measure uA/mA current without breaking the circuit?

Tags: current-measurement

I was wondering if there is any known way of measuring DC current without breaking the circuit? 
I have an application where breaking the circuit simply isn't an option but we still have to verify power consumption.

I'm aware of the following product but it's range is above what I need measure: http://www.aimtti.com/go/iprober/

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Hall effect?  Fluke makes a clamp on process ammeter that reads from from 4 to 20 mA with 10 uA resolution.

Comment: Is there any existing resistive element in series with the current to be measured? For example, a resistor, inductor, or ferrite bead? First measure the DC resistance of that element (out of circuit). Then measure voltage across the element in normal operating conditions.

Comment: In case someone else can think of a way around your limitation that you can't break the circuit, please can you explain exactly why that isn't possible? Some information about the power source(s) and the device involved would also be helpful. There have been other "I can't use the normal approach because of limitation X" questions, where it turns out there *was* a (previously not considered) solution for limitation "X" when it was revealed, and that solution allowed a normal approach for the underlying problem. Unless you reveal your limitation "X" then readers here can't help with that :-)

Comment: you don't have to break the circuit to insert something to the circuit. e.g. you can put a sensor in parallel with a section of wire then cut wire. the circuit is connected the whole time.

Comment: There is a µCurrent probe developed by Dave at EEVBLOG

Comment: @MarkoBuršič - Indeed, I use mine often, and that would be a normal solution for this type of question - except the OP has excluded normal "series" solutions by his stated constraint. So either we have to be "creative" about getting such a device in series with the +ve supply, or else it fails to meet the that constraint. That is why I asked more about the constraint, to see if anyone can find a way to allow normal solutions, like the uCurrent, or to see if clever approaches, like *user3528438* suggested, can be used. Now waiting for further explanation of the stated constraint from the OP...

Comment: If you use a clamp on or other toroidal type sensor, you can wrap several turns around the sensor and to gain sensitivity.  i.e. 10 turns will display a value ten times the actual current

Comment: Can you loop the wire into several turns? It will add inductance but will increase the resolution of a hall effect meter.

Comment: What I have done in the past is use a mA meter, with a jumper in parallel. This allows the device to operate with low series resistance until it gets into its low-power state. Then I temporarily remove the jumper to get an accurate read on the current in its low-current state.